# What is the graph with $8$ vertices and $12$ edges that has the most spanning trees?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, combinatorics, spanning-trees

I'm not sure if this is an open question, but what is the graph with $8$ vertices and $12$ edges that has the most spanning trees?

Comment: Hello! We discourage posts that simply state a question out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question will be voted to be closed / downvoted. You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/), or use the search engine of this site to find similar questions that were already answered.

Answer (score 4):

It is not too hard to search for it using [SageMath](http://cloud.sagemath.com). The graph you are looking for seems to be the [Wagner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner_graph) graph.

It takes a couple of minutes to run, you can check it yourself [here](https://x0.no/luv8).